# Extract personal id number on a Wit.ai story

Tags: wit.ai

I have a story that asks the user for its personal id number and i'm getting troubles to extract that value from the user input. My story is very simple, it just asks the user for that value. I used the builtin entity ***wit/number*** and (here goes the difficult to fix this problem), most of the times the user input is classified as a number, but sometimes (this is the problem) **sometimes not**. 
Any suggestions / hints on how to accomplish this?
An example of the dialog is:

```
[bot]: What is your personal id number?
[user]: 9842999
[bot]:  ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Update: I was able to replicate this isssue! Here is the logs from the conversation:

```
INFO 2016-12-06 18:30:07,468 Person ID not found. Entity 'number' not found on bot response
DEBUG 2016-12-06 18:30:07,468 Bot Response: {'action': 'save_id', 'type': 'action', 'entities': {'yes_no': [{'value': '32999222', 'type': 'value', 'suggested': True, 'confidence': 0.5289867882533972}]}, 'confidence': 1}
```

As you can see, wit doenst match the personal id '32999222' with te 'wit/number' entity. Instead its thinks that 'yes_no' entity applies.

Comment: Can you update this question with two or three examples each of input classified as a number and input not classified as such?

Comment: Unfortunately i didn't save cases of numbers that were not recognized by the entity wit / number. I'll be working today to try to replicate this issue. If i succeed, i'll update it here. Thanks @HEATH3N .

Comment: I was able to replicate this issue, Updating my question :)